# Open .blend files on nautilus with snap installed version of blender

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus, snap, blender

Over nautilus I have a `.blend` file and whilst I double click it I want to be opened with blender. I have installed the blender via snap instead of apt derived one.

The problem is that when I double click it to open it prompts me to a window in order to search for a program instead of opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command over the terminal

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Or:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Then append the following entry to the end of it:

```
application/x-blender=blender.desktop
```

Also this can be done via the following command:

```
echo "application/x-blender=blender.desktop" >> ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: Also of note is that the apt installed blender should put the [blender.desktop](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/freedesktop/blender.desktop) file into position so that it becomes part of the mime database. The missed step with using snap would be either installing blender.desktop or updating the mime database after install.